How to efficiently convert denormalized data to JSON?
I am learning django and couldn't find an answer on this.
I am receiving data a query in denormalized form. Here is how it looks like.



Store_id
Shelf_id
Product_id
Qty




store1
shelf1
product1
20


store1
shelf1
product2
24


store1
shelf2
product1
34


store1
shelf2
product3
12


store2
shelf1
product3
21


store2
shelf1
product1
46



and so on. There is one-to-many relationships from store to shelf to product models. I have written a foreach loop to go over the entire dataset and convert it to JSON like
[
  {"store1" : [
    {"shelf1" : [
      {"product1" : 20}, 
      {"product2" : 24}]
    }, 
    {"shelf1" : [...]}]
  },
  {"store2" : [...]},
]

Although, the foreach loop is pretty straightforward to write, it is pretty inefficient in the execution. For every record, it has to check if the store and shelf exists before adding the product entry. The production data is expected to have 100+ stores and 5000+ shelves and be about 1.5MM rows per day. That is a large number of key lookups. Is there a way one can generate the data in JSON format directly out of django queries?

The table looks correctly formatted in preview mode. Don't know why it is not maintaining that formatting in the final question.

Can there be duplicates: i.e. the same store_id, shelf_id and product_id?

No. store_id, shelf_id and product_id columns forms the composite key for the output. One of the questions we are trying to answer is if a particular product is being stored in multiple places in the same store?
